# Quaternion Kalman Filter Process Noise

Tags: stochastic-processes, quaternions, covariance, bayesian-network, kalman-filter

I'm implementing a extended Kalman filter using quaternions.

I've extended this [paper](http://www.ent.mrt.ac.lk/iml/paperbase/TRO%20Collection/TRO/2006/december/11.pdf) to deal with my custom observations.

My state space is analogous to the one in the previous paper : 
$
\mathbf{x}=[r_x, r_y, r_z, q_w, q_x, q_y, q_z]^T
$
with $\mathbf{r}$ the angle rate vector and $\mathbf{q}$ the quaternion.

**Here is my problem** : in the paper from Xiaoping, the process noise matrix is null everywhere except on the 3 first elements of the diagonal where small equals values are considered.

With this approach, we are not considering any process noise on the quaternion components, only on the angle rates. I seems like an oversimplification to me.

I've tried to put some noise on the rest of the diagonal, but i expect the quaternion components to be correlated to each others due to the normalization procedure rotation quaternions suffers.

Right now i'm searching for a more realistic process noise matrix but i can't find the information anywhere. Does anyone have an idea of what this process noise matrix should look like ?

Best :) ,

Comment: Side note: a much better way to represent quaternions in a Kalman filter is using the methods in the following paper (Integrating Generic Sensor Fusion Algorithms with Sound State Representations through Encapsulation of Manifolds), rather than having 4 components in the state vector. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4613/727ef686c6186cab69e6b8be8cb1fa3ba800.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that quaternion process noise makes sense?

The equation for a quaternion update is:

$\dot{q} = \frac12 q \otimes \omega$

There's no noise in this process; if you knew $\omega$ perfectly, you could integrate $q$ perfectly.

All noise should be introduced through $\omega$.